Should one prefer "a" or "an" when the pronunciation of the following word is ambiguous?
Take the example, "A(n) SQL database".
For those who don't know, SQL is an acronym short for "Structured Query Language". It may be pronounced as either the letters "S", "Q", and "L", or identical to the word "sequel". This is generally a matter of personal preference / idiolect.
Depending on the initial sound of the word - either "see" or "ess" - it would be appropriate to use "a" or "an" when speaking. In writing, however, one cannot predict whether a user might read "sequel" or "ess-queue-ell". In such situations, is there an established convention to use either "a" or "an" when there is no clear correct choice?

Hello, Josh. The default usage of acronym has the 'read as if a single word' caveat. Check in most dictionaries; they've updated their entries. So SOAS and UNESCO (and radar) are by this definition acronyms, whereas UCL and UN are not; this second set are known as  initialisms. If you're right about pronunciation, SQL is sometimes one, sometimes the other. A useful example to remember.

There is a candidate for duplicity: Do you use a or an before acronyms and initialisms? But it doesn't address the default choice when the abbreviation is seen as indeterminate between the forms (ie there is divided usage).

For a related ambiguity see Is it supposed to be a HTML or an HTML

The correct use of "a" or "an" is determined by the pronunciation of the following word rather than its spelling. If both vowel-led and consonant-led pronunciations are acceptable, then both indefinite articles are acceptable as well. From a style perspective, choose whichever pronunciation seems more common, or if there is no clear winner, just pick one and stick with it.

I usually use 'a' in 'a NP' as I always expand when speaking (though obviously when analysing, expansion may be out of the question). But can you cite an authority which clearly widens the 'the correct use of "a" or "an" is determined by the pronunciation of the following word {with grey areas including 'a/an hotel / historian ...'] to specifically include acronyms/initialisms normally expanded on reading aloud? I'd say it won't be more than a style recommendation, and I've never even seen even that.
